# C# Extension Method for String Data Type

Tags: c#, string, extension-methods, numbers

My web application deals with strings that need to be converted to numbers a lot - users often put commas, units (like cm, m, g, kg) and currency symbols in these fields so what I want to do is create a string extension method that cleans the field up and converts it to a decimal.

For example:

```
decimal myNumber = "15 cm".ToDecimal();
```

Comment: After reading "...people get carried away", I wish I hadn't posted. Perhaps if you asked the right question instead of bringing currency into the equation you might get the answer you were looking for, rather than coming out of this sounding really ungrateful. It seems to me you got "carried away" with your question. If you really are going to use string manipulation for currency parsing, good luck to you.

Comment: I apologize for offending you and I do appreciate everyone's input, however, as the post is entitled, what I was looking for was a way to create a string extension method, for whatever reason.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you expecting users of different 'cultures' to use your application? If so it's better to factor in the user's regional settings:

```
static decimal ToDecimal(this string str)
{
    return Decimal.Parse(str, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
}
```

Or you could replace every character in str that isn't a digit or the `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator` value and then parse it as a decimal.

**EDIT:**
It is generally accepted that extension methods should have their own namespace. This will avoid naming conflicts and force the end user to selectively import the extensions they need.

Comment: Thanks. It is important to note that for the above implementation, the extension method's containing STATIC CLASS must be in the same NAMESPACE as the extended class, otherwise you will have to INCLUDE the namespace in which the extension method is contained.

Comment: @Jimbo: Actually it is recommended that you create a seperate namespace for your extension methods and force people to import them. One reason being that extension methods can be specific to a particular business domain; not every developer will want to see every extension method, especially if you have a lot. In this case a contrived example namespace could be `namespace Extensions.Currency`.

Answer (score 6):

An extension method is of the following form:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static decimal ToDecimal(this string input)
    {
        //your conversion code here
    }
}
```

- The containing class must be static.
  The method is also static Note the
  "this" keyword. I recommend the
  convention of grouping extension
  methods by the type to which they
  refer, but there is no requirement to
  do so.

Here is a [guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) for writing extension methods.

Answer (score 1):

Please read this article about currency implementations:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/locale/currency-formatting

Example:

```
Double myNumber = Double.Parse("$1,250.85", NumberStyles.Any);
```

PS. You trying parse floating point value to decimal type.

Comment: This is reading the currency, and very nice, thank you - however, I would like to know how to make a string extension method anyway :P

Comment: @Jimbo: myNumber.ToString("C");

Answer (score 1):

```
public static double ToDecimal(this string value)
{
    ... your parsing magic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most appropriate way to solve this problem seems to me to be to use the overload of `Decimal.TryParse` that accepts a `NumberStyles` and a culture. Pass it `NumberStyles.Currency` and an appropriate culture.

Now, there's nothing stopping you providing an extension method on `string` that calls this - but you do need to consider what you would like the value of `d` to be after

```
decimal d = "ponies".ToDecimal();
```

Comment: Is it possible to overload `Decimal.TryParse`? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem is that you must know the Culture in which the user enters the number. Otherwise you will run into big problems.

A little example is the to read your number as english or german one.

In english the [NumberFormatInfo.CurrencyDecimalSeparator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencydecimalseparator.aspx) is a dot (.) and the [NumberFormatInfo.CurrencyGroupSeparator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencygroupseparator.aspx) is a comma (,). In german it is exactly the other way around. So you can start wild guessing if the user means one thousand two hundred fifty or one and a fourth dollar.

Maybe you can run over all available Cultures and check if your user input contains a [NumberFormatInfo.CurrencySymbol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencysymbol.aspx) and then try the given culture. But maybe there are cultures which use the same Symbol but different Separators.

So to get this really to work you have just two really choices:
* Tell your users in which culture format they have to enter their values.
* Give the user the possibility to tell you which culture they decided to do.

A list of all available cultures can be get by [CultureInfo.GetCultures()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.getcultures.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Just answering the how do I create extension method for string class:

```
public static class MyStringExtensions {
public static ToDecimal(this string input) {
   // ...
}
}
```

(and you need to have an using statement for the namespace it is located in order to use it)