# if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(myString)) and if (String.IsNullOrWhitespace(myString)) still working for empty strings

Tags: c#, if-statement

my goal is to get a message from an other client over a server and work on with that message. Server and other client are in visual basic and if i try to communicate between two vb clients everything is fine, but i need the client in c# for my Unityproject. 
My Problem is that there are still empty Messages at the Console, so i think the if() doesn't work correct.
Here is the relevant part of the Code:

```
try
            {
                theStream = mySocket.GetStream();
                Byte[] inStream = new Byte[mySocket.SendBufferSize];
                theStream.Read(inStream, 0, inStream.Length);
                serverMsg += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream);
                serverMsg = serverMsg.Trim();

                //if ((serverMsg == null || serverMsg == "")) doesn't work
                //if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(serverMsg)) doesn't work
                //if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(serverMsg) || serverMsg.Length <1) doesn't work  
                INOWS = false;
                INOWS = IsNullOrWhiteSpace(serverMsg);

                if (INOWS) 
                {
                    // do nothing
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.Log("[SERVER] -> " + serverMsg);

                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.Log("[Fehler]" + e);
            }
        } while (socketReady == true);
public static bool IsNullOrWhiteSpace(string value)
{
    if (value != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!char.IsWhiteSpace(value[i]))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Thanks to your hints i tried using IsNullOrWhiteSpace, but this gave me an error `"'string' does not contain a definition for IsNullOrWhiteSpace"`
So i used [this IsNullOrWhitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30649374/9418954) but i still get at least one empty string at the console for every korrekt string. [console view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EVXq.png) Do you have any other hints for me?

Comment: Note that Trim does not edit the string. It returns a new string that has been trimmed.

Comment: Also, you could just use `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`.

Comment: Using SendBufferSize to *read* makes no sense whatsoever.  4096 is a nice round value.  Trim() does not remove the zeros from the buffer, nor is it used correctly.  Pay attention to the return value of Read(), it tells you how many bytes are actually in the buffer and what you need to pass to GetString().

Comment: You should really avoid writing `catch (Exception e)` - it leads to swallowing errors and giving you the false sense of security that your code is bug-free.

Comment: the marked "duplicates" didn't bring the solution, it's still not working. Thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: What is the exact value of `value`? `value.Length`? `value.Trim().Length`?

Comment: serverMsg.Trim() is the value

Comment: I asked three questions. You answered none of them. The latter two questions, for example, would have a **number** as the answer.

Comment: so i missunderstood your question, sorry.
value is like:  Quelle-95-94-true
length: different but always Name-XPos-YPos-boolean
Trim.Length should be the same as length, but if there were Spaces, it should remove them

Answer (score 1):

```
if (String.IsNullOrWhitespace(serverMsg))                    
                {
                    // do nothing
                }
```

`IsNullOrWhitespace()` checks `null`, whitespace("   ") and empty("")

Comment: I tried it with IsNullOrWhitespace() and edited my Question, because it poorly didn't work for me

Comment: @mjwills You're right, I just copied and pasted it and added the NullOrWhitesapce. I will update now

Answer (score -1):

Try trimming the string:  if the string has any whitespace characters in it, it will still fail the IsNullOrEmpty() test.

In such cases (particularly with user or web service input), I generally use something like

```
if ((s ?? "").Trim() != "")
{
  //  do whatever processing you need to do here...
  ...
)
```

Comment: I guess that's what `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` is for! Why reinvent the wheel?